# Python HTML fill and submit form

Tags: python, html, forms, python-requests, lxml

I am trying to write a Python script that goes to a form on a internal website (with the name "DefaultForm") and fills in the input name="username" field in the form with 'user001', the input name="password" field with 'pass001' and click on submit

Tried doing this with Selenium and it works. But want to accomplish the same task with Requests(and BeautifulSoup for some html scraping later on)

Code I wrote which does NOT work!

```
url = 'http://SERVER:PORT/dashboard/portal'
payload = {'username':'user001','password':'pass001'}
r = requests.get(url, params=payload)
print(r.text)
```

I check the content in r.text before and after the requests.get(..) and both are the same.

Can anyone help me on how to do this ?

**Edit/Update:** Also tried this to submit my form using lxml but there seems to be an error which i can't seem to get my head around

```
page = parse(url).getroot()
page.forms[0].fields['username'] = 'user001'
page.forms[0].fields['password'] = 'pass001'
result = parse(submit_form(page.forms[0]).encode('utf-8')).getroot()
print(result.text)
```

This is the console result i get

> runfile('C:/Users/mgreza/Downloads/WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.3/notebooks/temp.py',
>   wdir='C:/Users/mgreza/Downloads/WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.3/notebooks')
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('C:/Users/mgreza/Downloads/WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.3/notebooks/temp.py',
>   wdir='C:/Users/mgreza/Downloads/WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.3/notebooks')
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\mgreza\Downloads\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.3\python-3.5.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 841, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\mgreza\Downloads\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.3\python-3.5.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 103, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File
>   **"C:/Users/mgreza/Downloads/WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.3/notebooks/temp.py",**
>   **line 13, in** 
>       **result = parse(submit_form(page.forms[0]).encode('utf-8')).getroot()**
>
> File
>   **"C:\Users\mgreza\Downloads\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.3\python-3.5.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\lxml\html__init__.py",**
>   **line 1110, in submit_form**
>       **return open_http(form.method, url, values)**
>
> File
>   **"C:\Users\mgreza\Downloads\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.3\python-3.5.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\lxml\html__init__.py",**
>   **line 1131, in open_http_urllib**
>       **return urlopen(url, data)**
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\mgreza\Downloads\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.3\python-3.5.1.amd64\lib\urllib\request.py",
>   line 162, in urlopen
>       return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\mgreza\Downloads\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.3\python-3.5.1.amd64\lib\urllib\request.py",
>   line 463, in open
>       req = meth(req)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\mgreza\Downloads\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.3\python-3.5.1.amd64\lib\urllib\request.py",
>   line 1170, in do_request_
>       raise TypeError(msg)
>
> **TypeError: POST data should be bytes or an iterable of bytes. It
>   cannot be of type str.**

Please help!!!!!!!

This is the page I am trying to submit

```html
<html>

<head>



  <base href="http://SERVER/DIRECTORY">


  <link href="css/default.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">


  <title>XYZ</title>


</head>

<body bgcolor="#ffffff">




  <p>&nbsp;</p>




  <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>

          <form method="POST" name="DefaultForm" action="http://SERVER/DIRECTORY" onsubmit="return (isReady(this));" autocomplete="off" _lpchecked="1">

            <input name="action" type="hidden" value="JLoginUser">
            <input name="serverTimeStamp" type="hidden" value="1467104268529">
            <input name="clientTimeStamp" type="hidden" value="1467104268904">
            <input name="clientIP" type="hidden" value="10.221.12.67">

            <table height="400" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="540" align="center" background="images/bkground.gif" border="0">

              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <table heigh="395" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" background="images/Transparent.gif" border="0">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td>
                            <img height="19" src="images/Transparent.gif">
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <img src="images/logo.gif" align="top" border="0">
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <img height="19" src="images/Transparent.gif" width="8">
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td width="10">
                            <img height="1" src="images\Transparent.gif" width="10">
                          </td>
                          <td valign="top" width="497">
                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" background="images/Transparent.gif" border="0">
                              <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                  <td valign="top" align="left" width="90"><span>&nbsp;</span> 
                                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" background="images/Transparent.gif" border="0">
                                      <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td width="4">&nbsp;</td>
                                          <td>
                                            <img height="1" src="images/Transparent.gif" width="5">
                                          </td>
                                          <td><span>&nbsp;</span>
                                          </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
                                        </tr>
                                      </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                  </td>
                                  <td width="18">
                                    <img height="1" src="images/Transparent.gif" width="18">
                                  </td>
                                  <td valign="top">
                                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" background="images/Transparent.gif" border="0">
                                      <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td valign="top" colspan="2" height="15">
                                            <p>
                                              <img height="15" src="images/Transparent.gif" width="1">
                                            </p>
                                          </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td valign="top" align="center" colspan="2">
                                            <img src="images/Integrator_login.gif">

                                          </td>
                                        </tr>

                                        <tr>
                                          <td colspan="2">
                                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" background="images/Transparent.gif" border="0">
                                              <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                  <td valign="top" align="center">
                                                    <div id="xboxLogin">
                                                      <b class="xtop"><b class="xb1"></b><b class="xb2"></b><b class="xb3"></b><b class="xb4"></b><b class="xb5"></b></b>
                                                      <div class="xboxLoginContent">

                                                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="200" background="images/Transparent.gif" border="0">
                                                          <tbody>
                                                            <tr>
                                                              <td valign="bottom" align="left" width="11" height="11"></td>
                                                              <td height="11">
                                                                <img height="11" src="images/Transparent.gif" width="1">
                                                              </td>
                                                              <td height="11">
                                                                <img height="11" src="images/Transparent.gif" width="1">
                                                              </td>
                                                              <td valign="bottom" align="right" width="11" height="11"></td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                              <td width="11">&nbsp;</td>
                                                              <td class="loginForm" colspan="2">Please sign in</td>

                                                              <td width="11">&nbsp;</td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                              <td width="11">&nbsp;</td>
                                                              <td class="loginForm">&nbsp;</td>
                                                              <td height="11">
                                                                <img height="11" src="images/Transparent.gif" width="1">
                                                              </td>
                                                              <td width="11">&nbsp;</td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                              <td width="11">&nbsp;</td>
                                                              <td class="loginForm">User ID</td>
                                                              <td height="11">
                                                                <img height="11" src="images/Transparent.gif" width="1">
                                                              </td>
                                                              <td width="11">&nbsp;</td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                              <td width="11">&nbsp;</td>
                                                              <td class="loginForm" colspan="2">
                                                                <input class="inputStyle" type="Input" name="username" size="20" style="cursor: pointer; background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,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&quot;); background-attachment: scroll; background-size: contain; background-position: 98% 50%; background-repeat: no-repeat;"
                                                                autocomplete="off">
                                                              </td>

                                                              <td width="11">&nbsp;</td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                              <td width="11" height="5">&nbsp;</td>
                                                              <td height="5">&nbsp;</td>
                                                              <td height="11">
                                                                <img height="11" src="images/Transparent.gif" width="1">
                                                              </td>
                                                              <td width="11" height="5">&nbsp;</td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                              <td width="11">&nbsp;</td>
                                                              <td class="loginForm">Password</td>
                                                              <td height="11">
                                                                <img height="11" src="images/Transparent.gif" width="1">
                                                              </td>
                                                              <td width="11">&nbsp;</td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                              <td width="11">&nbsp;</td>
                                                              <td colspan="2">
                                                                <input class="inputStyle" type="password" maxlength="28" name="password" size="20" style="cursor: auto; background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,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&quot;); background-attachment: scroll; background-size: contain; background-position: 98% 50%; background-repeat: no-repeat;"
                                                                autocomplete="off">
                                                              </td>

                                                              <td width="11">&nbsp;</td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                              <td width="11" height="5">&nbsp;</td>
                                                              <td height="5">&nbsp;</td>
                                                              <td height="11">
                                                                <img height="11" src="images/Transparent.gif" width="1">
                                                              </td>
                                                              <td width="11" height="5">&nbsp;</td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                              <td width="6">&nbsp;</td>
                                                              <td class="loginForm">
                                                                <input class="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Sign In" style="font-size:10">
                                                              </td>
                                                              <td width="50%" align="center">&nbsp;</td>

                                                              <td width="11">&nbsp;</td>
                                                            </tr>

                                                            <tr>
                                                              <td valign="top" align="left" width="11" height="11"></td>
                                                              <td height="11">
                                                                <img height="11" src="images/Transparent.gif" width="1">
                                                              </td>
                                                              <td height="11">
                                                                <img height="11" src="images/Transparent.gif" width="1">
                                                              </td>
                                                              <td valign="top" align="right" width="11" height="11"></td>
                                                            </tr>

                                                          </tbody>
                                                        </table>
                                                      </div>
                                                      <b class="xbottom"><b class="xb5"></b><b class="xb4"></b><b class="xb3"></b><b class="xb2"></b><b class="xb1"></b></b>
                                                    </div>
                                                  </td>
                                                  <td width="43">
                                                    <img height="8" src="images/Transparent.gif" width="43">
                                                  </td>

                                                </tr>
                                              </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                          </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td valign="top" align="left">&nbsp;</td>
                                          <td valign="top" align="right" colspan="3">

                                          </td>
                                        </tr>
                                      </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                              </tbody>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>


                      </tbody>

                    </table>


                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </form>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

**EDIT/UPDATE:** Logs when POST-ing form

**Request Header:-**

`Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.6
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:140
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:JSESSIONID=1ax740u3chasqa4rmen8ifq5b; SCI_DLSSO=U2Vzc2lvbklEaGl1YWFseGJqeGx1MTN1OGFtaXpva3Yybw==
Host:10.1.28.189:5010
Origin:http://SERVER:PORT
Referer:http://SERVER:PORT/dashboard/
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36`

**Response Header:-**

`Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires:Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified:Thu, 30 Jun 2016 01:47:48 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID=17zql1r4hdylrfg54lardx14p;Path=/dashboard/;HttpOnly
Set-Cookie:SCI_DLSSO=U2Vzc2lvbklEMTd6cWwxcjRoZHlscmZnNTRsYXJkeDE0cA==;Path=/;HttpOnly
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-FRAME-OPTIONS:SAMEORIGIN`

**Form Data:-**

`action=JLoginUser&serverTimeStamp=1467251264480&clientTimeStamp=2146&clientIP=10.220.12.101&username=user001&password=pass001&submit=Sign+In`

Comment: It is a post request and it gives you the url in the action atttribute

Comment: Hi @Padraic Yes, you are correct! Still no idea how to make this work

Comment: Hi @rsm I tried the solution you mentioned, it still doesn't work for me.

Comment: Can you share the url?

Comment: Hi @Padraic the URL is an org-internal URL so you would not be able to open it Anyways here it is. http://10.1.45.165:5101/dashboard/portal/. Also please check the updated question, i have added more information

Comment: when you monitor the post in chrome tools/firebug what gets posts as form data?

Comment: Hi @Padraic I have updated the Request/Response Headers and Form Data into the question

Comment: I added an answer that should work, just make sure the urls are correct.

Answer (score 2):

This should get you loggeg in:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

with requests.Session() as s:
    xml = .get("http://SERVER:PORT/dashboard/portal").getroot()
    form = xml.xpath("//form[@name='DefaultForm']")[0]
    print(form.xpath("./input[@name]"))
    data = {i.xpath("@name")[0] : i.xpath("@value")[0] for i in form.xpath("./input[@name]")}
    post_url = form.xpath("@action")[0]
    data["username"] = "username"
    data["password"] = "password"
    data["submit"] = "Sign In"
    r = s.post("http://SERVER:PORT/dashboard/portal"", data=data)
```